# Storing data are no sensitive in the application forever

Tags: ios, keychain

I want to save no sensitive data in my app,
The data not delete when the app delete.
I saved in keychain but I see that In keychain save only sensitive data.
where I can to save my data?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such place on iOS where you can save data that stays on the device even if your app is deleted, except for the keychain...

This is because your app is running in a *Sandbox* that holds all the data that belongs to your app. You have a few possibilities to achieve persistence *within* the context of your app (e.g. using the *Documents directory* of your app, `NSUserDefaults` or *Core Data*,...), but for any of these, there is the restriction that the data gets deleted along with the app.

Comment: I can store in keychain  data  not sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to store the data in the cloud, either writing your own server side system to store the information or using a service like Parse.com